# Using SCROLLINFO struct and SetScrollInfo()

Tags: winapi, scrollbar

I'm still fairly new to Win32 API. I'm primarily a C++ Programmer.

I'm trying to make my scrollbar thumb proportional to the page size, by using SetScrollInfo and nPage.
It's my understanding that this is one of the better ways of doing that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO 
{
    UINT cbSize;
    UINT fMask;
    int  nMin;
    int  nMax;
    UINT nPage;
    int  nPos;
    int  nTrackPos;
} SCROLLINFO, *LPCSCROLLINFO; // I don't have an understanding of what these 
                              // following variables(?) are: "SCROLLINFO", "*LPCSROLLINFO"

SCROLLINFO mainVertScroll;
mainVertScroll.cbSize    = 0;
mainVertScroll.fMask     = SIF_ALL;
mainVertScroll.nMin      = 0;
mainVertScroll.nMax      = 0;
mainVertScroll.nPage     = 0;
mainVertScroll.nPos      = 0;
mainVertScroll.nTrackPos = 0;

// ...

::SetScrollInfo(ghMainWnd, SB_VERT, ? , true);
```

What pointer am I to include into SetScrollInfo to direct it to the scrollbar parameters I have declared in mainVertScroll?

### Code Extract

```
// bitmapDraw.cpp

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "resource.h"

//=======================================================
// Globals

HINSTANCE ghAppInst = 0;
HWND      ghMainWnd = 0;

HBITMAP   ghBitMap  = 0;

// Step 1: Define and implement main window procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK
WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
// Objects for paint
HDC hdc   = 0;
HDC bmHDC = 0;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO 
{
    UINT cbSize;
    UINT fMask;
    int  nMin;
    int  nMax;
    UINT nPage;
    int  nPos;
    int  nTrackPos;
} SCROLLINFO, *LPCSCROLLINFO;

SCROLLINFO mainVert;
mainVert.cbSize    = 0;
mainVert.fMask     = SIF_ALL;
mainVert.nMin      = 0;
mainVert.nMax      = 0;
mainVert.nPage     = 0;
mainVert.nPos      = 0;
mainVert.nTrackPos = 0;

BITMAP bitmap = {0};

static int bmWidth  = 0;
static int bmHeight = 0;

HBITMAP oldBM = 0;

switch(msg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    ghBitMap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(ghAppInst, "childrenRunning.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    GetObject(ghBitMap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);

    bmWidth  = bitmap.bmWidth;
    bmHeight = bitmap.bmHeight;

    ::SetScrollInfo(ghMainWnd, SB_VERT, &mainVert, true);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

*Just do*

```
::SetScrollInfo(ghMainWnd, SB_VERT, &mainVertScroll, true);
```

and don't forget to set actual `cbSize`

```
mainVertScroll.cbSize = sizeof( SCROLLINFO );
```

*Regarding*:

> I don't have an understanding of what these following variables(?) are: "SCROLLINFO", "*LPCSROLLINFO"

When you want to create instance of `SCROLLINFO` in C you need to write

```
struct SCROLLINFO info;
```

So it's considered a good practice to `typedef` structs so that you can create objects without `struct` keyword.

So

```
typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO 
{
    ...
} SCROLLINFO, *LPCSCROLLINFO;
```

is the same as:

```
struct tagSCROLLINFO { ... };
typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO  SCROLLINFO;
typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO* LPCSCROLLINFO;
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan,  your explanations are very clear. I tried using a reference to my SCROLLINFO instance mainVertScroll like so: ::SetScrollInfo(ghMainWnd, SB_VERT, &mainVertScroll, true) but, I got the error "SCROLLINFO* is incompatible with parameter type LPCSCROLLINFO"